# react-native app is crashing when install in device

Tags: ios, swift, react-native

I am running react app from Xcode . It is working correctly when running in simulator and iPhone 6s . But when I upload it on hockey app and install it in same iPhone, app starts crashing after 5 second . Which is showing error

> com.facebook.react.AsyncLocalStorageQueue

Here is the Screenshot of error -

[image]

Comment: what is the data you save with `AsyncStorage`? it can only store string, so if you need to save an object, array or number you need to convert it to string first by using JSON.stringify()

Comment: @deepti-raghav how do you save the data in async storage? 
Do you have any state management with persistency?